# SQL show multiple values from same columns

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2 tables and I must do an inner join.

First table called `People`

```
Name, Surname, id, and value
```

Second table called `Work`

```
id (external key of fist table), category, state, roles, date.
```

Column "Roles" can have multiple values (employee director workers etc).

I must show with inner join the history of roles for each people in one row ( Name Surname roles1, roles 2 roles3)

Example Jack Brown employee director workers

How can I show in one row multiple values contained in one Columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to see the roles but don't really require them to be in separate columns you can use [`listagg()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

```
select p.id, 
       p.name, 
       p.surname, 
       listagg(w.roles, ',') within group (order by start_date) as all_rows
from people p
  join work w on p.id = w.id
group by p.id, p.name, p.surname
```

This would output something like this:

```
ID | NAME   | SURNAME | ALL_ROLES                
---+--------+---------+-------------------------
 1 | Jack   | Brown   | employee,worker,director
```

---

You can't actually have each role in a separate column, because in SQL the number of columns in a result is fixed. So you can't have a result that has three columns for the roles of "Jack Brown" and two column for the roles of "Arthur Dent".

Answer (score 0):

You could write PL-SQL function which will select all related records from table Work by given id from table People and iterate it in a cursor to build a string with all of roles or you could generate XML by using of [DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#CHEJCICB) function if you are using the 10g version of Oracle or higher

Comment: is not possible with simple innner join ?

Comment: Nope, simple joins can return more than one row for each record in the Person table in a case if more than 1 record in table Work related to that record in a table Person by id.

Comment: You can see illustration how SQL joins are working here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins